# Display year in calculated column in SharePoint

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am creating a column in SharePoint list. This column is calculated.

I am using below formula as of now: `=""&"INC0000"AutoID`

This shows results like: `INC00001`, `INC00002`, etc.

I want to change and show results like: `20151`, `20152`, etc.

Where `2015` is current year and `1`,`2` is ID.

If user enter data next year then output should be like `20161`, `20162`, and so on. Year should be current.

Please anyone can share formula for this. Thanks

Comment: Will this work? =CONCATENATE(([ContractNo],YEAR(CREATED)&autoID))

Answer (score 1):

Set the data type to Single line of text and add the below formula

```
=YEAR(Created)&AutoID
```

Comment: If Created is the default SP field then it will never be empty. The default ID however will be 0 for newly created items, see the workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986458/columns-dereferencing-in-sharepoints-calculated-column

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have edited my answer. The IF statement can be used if calculation is for some other field.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is old topic BUT ... the above suggestion `=YEAR(Created)` returns `10/09/1905` instead of the current year `2018`.

Instead I have used the following syntax: `=TEXT([Created],"yyyy")` which works fine on existing entries but if a new entry is done, it shows `1899` instead of year `2018`.

For some reasons the [ ] seem to disappear once it is reloaded.

Comment: That's because you selected Date as the output format of the Calculated column. Change it to Single Line of Text or Number to display "2018"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to base the value of the year on the record's created date if you want it to reflect the current year. And, assuming your "AutoID" field works and increments as expected, your formula would be as follows:

```
=YEAR(Created)&AutoID
```

Answer (score 0):

Bucki, make sure the data type of calculated column is set to "Number". I found that when the data type was set to Single Line of Text, the 1899 was being returned. Setting it as "Number" produced the expected result.